# What kind of design style is this website?

Tags: website-design, style-identification

What kind of style design is this website? https://ko-fi.com/.

I'm a pretty newbie frontend developer, I know that Material Design and Antdesign are pretty popular, but ko-fi.com doesn't look like those. I want to make a website for a school project with the design the same as ko-fi.com, but don't know what kind of design that is, it would be easier for me to know the name of the style, I then could find UI libraries to help me write code easier.

Another website that looks like that is https://lotus.vn/w. Btw it would be more helpful if you can guide me the way (or tools) to find out the kind of design instead of just giving me the name.

Comment: "it would be more easier for me to know the name of the design, I then could find UI libraries to help me write code easier" - most likely there isn't a library to help you create in this style because there isn't a library specific to most styles.

Comment: Which parts of the websites, specifically, are you asking about? Please include images of those parts in the question itself because these websites are likely to change and your question won't make sense when that happens.

Comment: If I threw another site like http://materialdesignblog.com/material-design-showcase/. The answer is obviously Material Design. Material Design is the name of the design that the site looks and feels. It's just that. Honestly, I don't have much vocabulary to describe what I want. Maybe the total white feel, the cards with subtle shadow, opensans font, images with graphic design. Maybe those are just specific to ko-fi.com? are there not the named design for those look and feel? I just felt a similar feeling, so I thought there's another site look the same as ko-fi, I just guess there's a name.

Comment: The thing is that design styles are quite hard to define. To define them strictly enough to perfectly describe a site makes them not general enough to accommodate differences. Ultimately everything is a mix of other things. It's better to search those terms that you just listed and take the parts that you want.

Comment: Thank you. I'm asking because I'm pretty new to design (to know that "design styles are quite hard to define. To define them strictly enough to perfectly describe a site makes them not general enough to accommodate differences. Ultimately everything is a mix of other things.") . Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find a library or a name specific to this styles.

Your examples are based off  Material Design patterns (cards, shadows, round corners, flat colors, white space) but with a twist of its own: shadows are very soft, custom color scheme, some images / illustrations, more white space...

So you should use the Material Design library and customize it to your liking. Use your own color palette, change the default font, customize border radius and shadows, add meaningful illustrations... Make it your own!

Comment: Thank you! Seems legit, just twist the current material design to fit my need huh.

Comment: @HuỳnhLợiNguyễn yup. Who knows, maybe _you_ can make a UI library based off your style? :)